# Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "как никто другой"?

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "как никто другой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это вводный оборот, который можно убрать из текста без вреда для содержания, поэтому он выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 2):

Ни в коем случае. Оборот это не вводный, а **сравнительный**, его **нельзя** убрать из текста без вреда для содержания (хотя грамматическая структура предложения и не разрушится при этом), он **не всегда** выделяется запятыми. Хотя **обычно** обособляется, да. Окончательное решение за автором текста. *(Меня тут, вероятно, считают уже параноиком?..)*

Comment: Ну, почему? Если убрать его из текста, предложение ведь не станет бессмысленным. Да, оно потеряет оттенок, но и только. "Он был трезв" - "Он, как никто другой, был трезв".

Answer (score 2):

Вот что я нашел на Грамоте.

[Вопрос № 212321](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=212321)

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли выражение "как никто другой" выделять запятыми?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Да, обособление нужно. Подробнее см. в «Справочнике по пунктуации».

[КАК НИГДЕ /…/ НИЧТО,  в составе сравнительного оборота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_334)

Сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся словами «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. д., **обособляются**

Но:

Обороты «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. п., тесно связанные со сказуемым и не имеющие при себе зависимых слов, **не обособляются**.

---

Мои выводы

Есть разница между оборотами «как никто» и «как никто другой». Первый может обособляться или нет, в зависимости от обстоятельств. Второй обособляется всегда.