# Проверка текста на предмет ошибок

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, стилистика, редактура

Проверьте, пожалуйста, текст на предмет пунктуационных, орфографических и стилистических ошибок.

«Книга о поступках» – вторая книга из серии «Живые стихи для детей», написанная молодой поэтессой Кирой Кудиновой.
Сама поэтесса называет свои стихотворения «живыми», так как каждое из них обладает реальным, интересным для детей сюжетом, подсказанным личным родительским опытом автора.
Мама двоих детей, Кира как никто другой знает, как важны складные, запоминающиеся поэтические строки в обучении маленького ребенка.
В легкой доступной форме стихи из «Книги о поступках» расскажут малышам о разных результатах совершения тех или иных поступков; помогут выработать здоровые способы реагирования на такие ситуации, как конфликт со сверстниками,  проигрыш в игре; напомнят о самостоятельности и важности развития навыков самообслуживания (одеваться, умываться, убирать за собой посуду и т.д.).
Стихи написаны простым понятным языком, пропитаны мягким юмором и добрыми ненавязчивыми наставлениями.
Также в серии «Живые стихи для детей» Кирой Кудиновой готовятся и другие издания.

Comment: Вы выбрали не тот сайт. ДЗ — не его профиль.

Comment: @shampar Как я понимаю, это не д/з. Kira (Кира) просит проверить аннотацию к своей книге.

Comment: Соответствует ли это профилю сайта?

Comment: Чем же проверка аннотации отличается от проверки сочинения? Сочинение — можно допустить — хотя бы самим автором написано. А здесь и этого нет.

Comment: В чем сейчас предмет спора?  Аннотацию писала я сама (я -автор).

Comment: Сочинение — часть учебного процесса. Предполагается, что сочинение пишет ученик без посторонней помощи, а учитель оценивает его работу. Другое дело — помощь молодым авторам.

Comment: Я  - автор. Дело в том, что я перепроверяю макет своих книг после редактора. Нахожу ошибки, к сожалению. И Вы мне очень помогаете, я вам очень благодарна.

Answer (score 1):

"В легкой доступной форме" — однородные определения, нужна запятая.

"Напомнят о самостоятельности" — хотелось бы улучшить (например: напомнят о необходимости проявлять самостоятельность)

"добрыми ненавязчивыми наставлениями" — не думаю, что это однородные.

"расскажут о разных результатах совершения поступков" — стиль какой-то странный, выпадает из общей тональности текста, написанного "простым, понятным языком".
Может, сказать "покажут результаты тех или иных поступков"? "расскажут, к чему приводят те или иные поступки"?

"Также в серии ..." — требует переделки (см. grizzly)

"важны (в?) обучении" — возможно, лучше сказать: "важны при обучении" или "важны в процессе обучения"

Я бы добавил слово "умения": "важности развития навыков самообслуживания (**умения** одеваться, умываться, убирать за собой посуду и т.д.).

Дополнение

Сомнительно: стихи пропитаны наставлениями. Пропитаны юмором — хорошо, но наставлениями? Как вариант:

Стихи написаны простым, понятным языком, пропитаны мягким юмором, **протканы/наполнены** добрыми ненавязчивыми наставлениями.

Answer (score 0):

Оборот "как никто другой" обособляется запятыми. См. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9).

"В легкой доступной форме" — здесь требуется запятая между однородными определениями или союз "и" между ними (я бы предпочёл союз). Не делают ли точки с запятой это предложение слишком тяжеловесным? Я бы внёс в него минимальные изменения:

"В легкой и доступной форме стихи из «Книги о поступках» расскажут малышам о разных результатах совершения тех или иных поступков, помогут выработать здоровые способы реагирования в ситуациях конфликта со сверстниками или проигрыша в игре,  напомнят о самостоятельности и важности развития навыков самообслуживания (одеваться, умываться, убирать за собой посуду и т.п.)."

"простым понятным языком", "добрыми ненавязчивыми наставлениями" — однородные определения отделяются друг от друга запятой.

"Также в серии «Живые стихи для детей» Кирой Кудиновой готовятся и другие издания." Я бы предпочёл такой стиль:

"В серии «Живые стихи для детей» готовятся к выпуску также другие книги Киры Кудиновой."

Comment: А добрыми(,) ненавязчивыми?

Comment: @Alex_ander Тоже нужна запятая, конечно. Спасибо. Я отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую дополнить в отношении стиля уже сказанное.

1. "Как никто другой" выглядит чрезмерным после аргументации "мама двоих детей" (есть и другие такие мамы) - лучше упростить до напр. "хорошо знает".
2. Вместо "разных результатах" заслуживает внимания "последствиях" (ясно, что они "разные" для разных поступков), поскольку в буквальном смысле "результатом" совершения поступка (т. е. намерения, приведённого в действие) является сам поступок.

Answer (score 0):

«Книга о поступках» – вторая книга из серии «Живые стихи для детей», написанная молодой поэтессой Кирой Кудиновой. Стихотворения названы «живыми», так как каждое из них обладает реальным, интересным для детей сюжетом, подсказанным личным родительским опытом автора. Мама двоих детей, Кира как никто другой знает, как важны складные, запоминающиеся поэтические строки при обучении маленького ребенка.

В легкой, доступной форме стихи расскажут малышам о плохих и хороших поступках, помогут правильно реагировать на конфликт со сверстниками или проигрыш в игре, напомнят, как  важно быть самостоятельным (одеваться, умываться, убирать за собой посуду). Стихи написаны простым, понятным языком, пропитаны мягким юмором и добрыми ненавязчивыми наставлениями.

Также в серии «Живые стихи для детей» автором готовятся и другие издания.